# Pandas: new column where value is based on a specific value within subgroup

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe where I want to create a new column ("NewValue") where it will take the value from the "Group" with Subgroup = A.

```
   Group SubGroup    Value  NewValue
0      1        A        1        1
1      1        B        2        1
2      2        A        3        3
3      2        C        4        3
4      3        B        5       NaN
5      3        C        6       NaN
```

Can this be achieved using a groupby / transform function?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with filtered DataFrame in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['NewValue'] = df['Group'].map(df[df.SubGroup.eq('A')].set_index('Group')['Value'])
print (df)
   Group SubGroup  Value  NewValue
0      1        A      1       1.0
1      1        B      2       1.0
2      2        A      3       3.0
3      2        C      4       3.0
4      3        B      5       NaN
5      3        C      6       NaN
```

Alternative with left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `rename` column:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.SubGroup.eq('A'),['Group','Value']].rename(columns={'Value':'NewValue'})
df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df)
   Group SubGroup  Value  NewValue
0      1        A      1       1.0
1      1        B      2       1.0
2      2        A      3       3.0
3      2        C      4       3.0
4      3        B      5       NaN
5      3        C      6       NaN
```